# Http connection error on the blackberry real device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build a simple application for testing purpose in which I am making a simple Http connection .The code is running perfectly on the simulator but when I am testing the app on the real device it is  not returning any response code. I think there is some error in http connection .

Here is the code that I am using for http connection:

```
httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
```

The device that I am using is Blackberry 8520 v5.0.0.592

Also give me some tips on how to do the debuging of any app from real device using eclipse plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First things to check are: does the device have a BlackBerry Data Plan activated for it? If not insure that the APN is configured properly and try appending ;deviceSide=true to the URL: "http://www.google.com;deviceSide=true"

Comment: Yes the device has BB Data Plan. I have tried using deviceSide=true ,also enabled  the APN setting  leaving username and password blank. But it didnt work for me.

Comment: How did you specify the APN settings? What operator do you have?

Comment: Also, what BlackBerry OS versions do you need to support? If only 5.0 and newer, you should use the new Network API instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is enough that your program works with OS 5.0+, then try using [Network API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html):

```
ConnectionFactory f = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor descr = f.getConnection("http://www.google.com");

HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) descr.getConnection();
```

That piece of code tries to use the first available connection type. You can fine tune it if you want.

Regarding debugging, just install BlackBerry Desktop Software, connect your 8520 with the USB cable and from eclipse, click Run -> Debug As... -> BlackBerry Device.

Comment: I have tried this  but i got response code 302 both on simulator and real device .....do you have any idea regarding this .........!!!

Comment: HTTP response code 302 means that the resource you are looking for is found at a different URI which should be provided in the Location header: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: can you kindly tell that how to resolve this issue ( of response code 302)... if possible kindly give any source code.......

Comment: Well, that's what www.google.com is supposed to do (reply with 302), so I cannot see an issue here. Perhaps you should clarify your question, what do you actually want to do with http://www.google.com?

Comment: google.com was just for testing purpose , now when i am replacing it with a correct url but its **response code is 503** only on the real device . Can u kindly suggest me that how can i get the response code 200 on the real device

Comment: Response code 503 usually indicates that you have an error on the server side - especially if other domains such as www.google.com do not reply with 503. What does the response body say?

Answer (score 1):

The connection factory worked perfectly on the new devices, but didn't work with some of the older ones like the curve and bold. This is what solved it for me:

```
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();
BrowserFieldRequest Req = new BrowserFieldRequest("http://www.yourserver.com/");

InputStream inputStream = browserField.getConnectionManager().makeRequest(Req).openInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to redirect the link using following code:

```
 HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url1);

 hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
 hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
 InputStream is = null;
 String location =hc.getHeaderField("Location");

 HttpConnection hcc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(location);
 is = hcc.openDataInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add transport to address 
For example for connect via wi-fi :

```
httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://www.google.com;interface=wifi");
```

Comment: I am using the default connection. I think it should also work. Isn it