# blackberry programming with Java ME

Tags: blackberry, java-me, httpconnection

hi friends I am new to blackberry programming, I am getting problem while making HTTPConnection to send GET request to a php web service, following is the code I am trying,

```
    HttpConnection conn = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    String result = null;
    String url = "http://localhost/blackberry/locations.php?device_id="+id+"&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon
    try{
        conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
        conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");
        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
            in = conn.openInputStream();
            int chr;
            //xp.parse(in, handler);
            while((chr = in.read()) != -1){
                buff.append((char)chr);
            }
            result = buff.toString();
        }
        else{
            result = "Error in connection";
            return result;
        }

    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally{
        try {
            in.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

please suggest me solution,
Thanks

Regard.

Comment: Can you please be specific about what the problem is?

Comment: What is your problem? got any exception?

Comment: I am getting nullPointerException in the code above.

Comment: and the service returns xml data, that i want to get and push on screen, Thanks

Comment: which line you are getting the `nullpointerexception`?

Comment: You have to check where its happening. Just check with `if` condition and use `System.out.println`. I think you made the mistake on URL.

Comment: Hey Hi, print ex.printStackTrace() in catch(Exception ex) block & show that stackTrace here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- If you are using OS 5.0+, use the network API instead. For more details, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431963/http-connection-error-on-the-blackberry-real-device/5432330#5432330)
- You cannot connect to localhost from BlackBerry.
- Use [IOUtilities.streamToBytes](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/IOUtilities.html) instead of that while loop to read the data to a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my reputation does not allow me to comment. My guess is: you cannot connect to localhost, therefore the response code is different from HTTP_OK, therefore the input stream 'in' never gets opened and the variable 'in' is still null when the stream is about to be closed in the finally-block. Hence the NullPointerException.

Try to use `if (in != null) in.close();` instead.

Comment: now i am using ip address instead of localhost still getting the same nullpointerexception